# How to TTS Chinese using pyttsx

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I want to know how to text-to-speech Chinese using the python package 'pyttsx'. It seems to need some other modules like neospeech.

Comment: You have problem with package installation, you wrote some code which is not working? If you don't provide some details no one will be able to help you. Have you checked the examples at http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, neospeech is a language library. By installing it, you can just set the voice of pyttsx and tts Chinese as well.

Comment: That does not answer the question: do you NEED Neospeech? How to make it work, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a voice that supports Chinese before using `pyttsx3`:

Something like

```py
import pyttsx3


def get_chinese_voice(engine):
    """Get a Chinese voice"""
    voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
    for voice in voices:
        if "zh-CN" in voice.languages:
            return voice
        if "Chinese" in voice.name or "Mandarin" in voice.name.title():
            return voice

    raise KeyError(f"No Chinese voice found among {voices}")


engine = pyttsx3.init()

chinese_voice = get_chinese_voice(engine)
engine.setProperty("voice", chinese_voice.id)
engine.say("你好")
engine.runAndWait()
```